# Arduino reiniciando ao iniciar a execução de código python

Tags: python, arduino

sou novo na parte de desenvolvimento e principalmente em utilizar o Arduino. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web com python com algumas funções, uma delas é ligar e desligar uma lâmpada (o meu problema). Desenvolvi o código, utilizei alguns já pronto da web (para testes) e a grande questão é, ao executar o código python, o arduino simplesmente reinicia e não executa a conexão entre o código e o arduino. Observei que ao iniciar a conexão (conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600), o problema ocorre. Testei com essa parte do código dentro do Try e o problema persiste. Alguém sabe o que pode está acontecendo e alguma ideia de como resolver? ps: estou utilizando o Pyserial.

Código python:

```
import serial
import time
from time import sleep

conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600) 
def escrever_porta():

   try: 
       valor = (raw_input("Digite o valor a ser enviado: "))
       conexao.write(valor)
       conexao.close()

   except serial.SerialException:
       print"ERRO: Verifique se ha algum dispositivo conectado na porta!"

   return valor
```

Código Arduino (já tentei vários):

```
#include "EmonLib.h"
#include <SPI.h>

int pin = 7;
char dados = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    while (Serial) {
      if (Serial.available()) {
        dados =(char)Serial.read();

        if (dados == "0") {
          delay(1);
          Serial.end();
          if (dados == "1") {
            digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
          } else {
            if (dados == "2") {
              digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
            }
          }
          dados = "" ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O código do python tá no Python2, haveria  chance do teu python ser o 3?
Se for, o código deverá ter algumas mudanças:

`raw_input` agora é `input`
e `print` terá parenteses `( counteúdo )`

```
import serial
import time
from time import sleep

conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600) 
def escrever_porta():

   try: 
       valor = (input("Digite o valor a ser enviado: ")) 
      #Esses parenteses antes do input é realmente necessário?
      #valor = input("Digite o valor a ser enviado: ")

       conexao.write(valor)
       conexao.close()

   except serial.SerialException:
   #tente também apenas "except:"
       print("ERRO: Verifique se ha algum dispositivo conectado na porta!")

   return valor
```

espero ter ajudado...
Se for o python realmente for 2.x, então o problema é só o `valor`

Comment: Então Antony, primeiramente obrigado pela a resposta.
Fiz as correções, a minha versão é o 2x, mais não é o problema :/.
Acredito que o problema seja na parte do código que cria uma conexão pela porta com3, simplesmente o arduino reinicia, o programa continua executando e sem nenhum erro, mais na hora de enviar os dados para a placa, nada acontece.

Comment: tente mudar tudo que se refere à variável `dados` com apenas uma aspa simples ( ' ) e não ( " ), talvez o erro esteja nesse segundo código. 

Tente também colocar abaixo do `valor` o comando: `conexao.open()`, eu olhei um pouco sobre esse pyserial e vi esse comando.

São apenas alguns chutes que dou, eu não tenho conhecimento na área, só tentando ajudar, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Tenha certeza que a porta está certa, é bastante comum os SOs jogarem o arduino para outra porta, vc realmente não está usando um porta serial virtual (FTDI)?

Comment: Sim, a porta está certa, o problema é apenas neste código.
Em um outro código com uma outra função, o arduino executa normalmente, a diferença com o que está descrito no post é que o outro código tem um while durante a sua execução.